# javascript: how to use different parameters?

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, html

I am supposed to make a variable description of a product using parameters. How do I make a function tell the parameters apart?

Parameter example:

```
buildProduct('HP 4426', '4426','Newest and Best Laptop from HP Computer') 
buildProduct('IBM 88123 ThinkPad', '88123','IBM micro Laptop Computer') 
buildProduct('Dell Dimension 2400', '2400X','A fast 2.4 ghz computer, 80 GB HD, 256       Meg, CDRW and DVD.')
```

Code:

```
function buildProduct(prodName, prodID, prodDescription) {
var data = makeHeader()
data +=" .....

    ..... output a simple one line description of the product using the parameters above
    ..... add the footer, after the one line description
    ..... use just one document.writeln in this function (see warning below)
    ..... close the document (see warning below)

}
```

So I have several different links, each opening a description window. How do I make the `HTML` tell which parameter to call?

I am having a bit of trouble understanding what is going wrong.

Comment: Can't you just put those variables in the html string? `'hello '+ variable +' world'`...

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? What happened?